# Which css selector can target elements with more than one class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm not sure how to properly word the title, but I have a list of divs and a few have an additional class of `.active`. I need to target only the first and last, but every selector I've tried is relative to the class that all items share, which is `.item` so I cannot achieve what I want.

```css
.active:first-child {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: green;
}

.active:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
</div>
```

None of these work. I have been messing with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/f0226073/2/

**Edit**
So I should have clarified this. I'm using Owl Carousel and am showing 3 items per slide. More `.item` divs can exist, but there will always be 3 `.active` divs. The selector would need to be dynamic in the sense that if more `.item`'s are added, then this won't affect the `.active` div selector.

Comment: So you want to select first and last div with active class?

Comment: Are you trying to select only those with the classes "active" ?

Comment: Yes, only `.active`, and it needs to be dynamic so if more `.item`'s exist, the first and last `.active` are targeted.

Comment: Will the `.active` always be consecutive (i.e., packed together), or can they be scattered around? Can there be a variable number, or always three?

Comment: It will always be "packed" together, never scattered. It will go down to 1 `.active` on mobile, but that's easy to manage with media queries.

Comment: since you're using owl carousel, you can update class names in js https://jsfiddle.net/dzda4tkc/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.item:not(.active) + .active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.active + .active + .active {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.active:first-child { /* in case .active is ever the first child */
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
</div>
```

Since there will always be three `.active` elements, and they will always be consecutive, the first selector will match the first `.active`, and the second selector will match the third one. The third selector is available in the event `.active` is the first of all siblings.

Also, assuming the styles will be the same, the three selectors can be consolidated into one:

```css
.item:not(.active) + .active,
.active + .active + .active,
.active:first-child {
  background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked, I kept adding `.item`'s and the `.active` divs remained targeted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First and last of `.active` divs:

html

```
<div class="item-container">
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item active">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
  <div class="item">123</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.active:nth-of-type(2n + 1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dt0qw3kv/2/

Comment: doesn't work as expected with more active classes https://jsfiddle.net/dt0qw3kv/1/

Comment: Sure, but his example shows three. You would certainly have to change the `n` value if there were more. If it's dynamically generated, then that's a whole different solution.

Comment: I should have clarified, there could be more `.item`, but there will always be 3 `.active` though. In the fiddle I added a couple of `.item`'s and the only the middle `.active` took the background color.

Comment: Will the `.actives` always be grouped?

Comment: Yeah, always grouped.

Comment: OK. Is my example not what you want? Just curious. The first and third are a different color (only used color as an example) - updated answer to use background color.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dt0qw3kv/3/ when I add more divs it doesn't achieve the proper targeting. The second `.active` is what becomes targeted.

Comment: Weird. I added a bunch more `divs` and still got the same results as my original solution, but I'm glad you were able to get the help you needed using Michael_B's answer. https://jsfiddle.net/dt0qw3kv/5/